# Where to ask a question regarding specific site rules and scope?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, asking-questions

I wonder where can ask a question regarding rules and standards of a specific site? For example I want to ask a question on "Chinese Language & Usage" about whether another question I have in mind will be (or not) suitable for that site? Obviously the site itself is not the place for asking such questions. But if not there, the only option I see - is here. But there is another problem, the people who use this site (Meta) do not necessary visit "CL&U"..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each SE site has its own meta site, the one for Chinese Language & Usage can be found at

https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/

And questions about the specific scope of a site do belong on the per-site meta, not here.